# Android game with SQlite database crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building a game app that a user can pick 1 out of 5 categories randomly and then questions will show with multiple choices. I created a database to hold the questions and answers. There are 5 tables of the questions who, what, when, where, why.

I checked on a DB browser and the Who category is created. I just wanted to try with that one first to see if I am on the right page. But the app crashes when the category loads. So after the category is picked an intent transfers over to the QuestionActiviy layout where it will load a question in a textView and give the user a chance to select the answer. But when I get to the QuestionActivity layout the app crashes.

Here is the database

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOG = "MySQLiteHelper";

    //Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quizQuestions";

    //Question Tables
    public static final String TABLE_WHO = "who";

    //Common Column names
    private static final String KEY_ID="id";

    //Who Table Column
    private static final String KEY_WHO_QUESTION="who_question";
    private static final String KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEA="who_multiple_choiceA";
    private static final String KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEB="who_multiple_choiceB";
    private static final String KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEC="who_multiple_choiceC";
    private static final String KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICED="who_multiple_choiceD";
    private static final String KEY_WHO_ANSWER="who_answer";
    //Create Who Table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WHO = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_WHO  + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_WHO_QUESTION
            + " TEXT," + KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEA + "Text," + KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEB + "Text," +
             KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEC + "Text," +KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICED + "Text," + KEY_WHO_ANSWER + "Text," + ")";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //create tables
        //Question Tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WHO);

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion) {
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WHO);


       onCreate(db);
        }


    public List<QuestionsTable> getAllWhos() {
        List<QuestionsTable> whoQuestions = new ArrayList<QuestionsTable>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_WHO;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                QuestionsTable allWhos = new QuestionsTable();
                allWhos.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                allWhos.setQuestion((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_QUESTION))));
                allWhos.setMultipleChoiceA(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEA)));
                allWhos.setMultipleChoiceB(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEB)));
                allWhos.setMultipleChoiceC(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEC)));
                allWhos.setMultipleChoiceD(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICED)));
                allWhos.setAnswer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WHO_ANSWER)));


                // adding to todo list
               whoQuestions.add(allWhos);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return whoQuestions;
    }

 //Create a Who item in the questions table
    public void createWhoItem(QuestionsTable quests) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, quests.getId());
        values.put(KEY_WHO_QUESTION, quests.getQuestion());
        values.put(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEA, quests.getMultipleChoiceA());
        values.put(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEB, quests.getMultipleChoiceB());
        values.put(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEC, quests.getMultipleChoiceC());
        values.put(KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICED, quests.getMultipleChoiceD());

        // insert row
        db.insert(TABLE_WHO, null, values);

    }

     //Who Questions
    public void addWhoQuestions() {
        QuestionsTable q1 = new QuestionsTable("Who was David's daughter?", "Tamar", "Macah", "Bathsheba",
                "Abigail", "Tamar");
        this.createWhoItem(q1);

        QuestionsTable q2 = new QuestionsTable("Who was Israel’s Firstborn son?", "Reuben", "Joseph", "Benjamin",
                "Judah", "Reuben");
        this.createWhoItem(q2);

        QuestionsTable q3 = new QuestionsTable("Who was the son of Jesse?", "Saul", "David", "Samson", "Goliath", "David");
        this.createWhoItem(q3);

        QuestionsTable q4 = new QuestionsTable("In Jesus' parable of the good Samaritan which of these passes by the injured man on the road?",
                "Priest", "Lawyer", "Servant", "Woman", "Servant");
        this.createWhoItem(q4);

        QuestionsTable q5 = new QuestionsTable("Who was not killed as part of satan's test in the book of Job, but for cursing God?",
                "Children", "Wife", "Friends", "Job", "Job");
        this.createWhoItem(q5);

        QuestionsTable q6 = new QuestionsTable("Who hired Delilah to cut Samson's hair?", "Philistines", "Israelites", "Agagites", "Amalekites", "Philistines");
        this.createWhoItem(q6);

        QuestionsTable q7 = new QuestionsTable("Who was known as the “weeping prophet?", "Ezekiel", "Jeremiah", "Isaiah", "Lamentations", "Jeremiah");
        this.createWhoItem(q7);

        QuestionsTable q8 = new QuestionsTable("Who was exiled on the isle of Patmos?", "John", "Paul", "Peter", "Onesimus", "John");
        this.createWhoItem(q8);

        QuestionsTable q9 = new QuestionsTable("Who was Moses father-in-law?", "Pharaoh", "Jethro", "Aaron", "Peter", "Jethro");
        this.createWhoItem(q9);

        QuestionsTable q10 = new QuestionsTable("Who did Solomon petition for supplies and workers for the temple?", "King of Tyre", "King of Syria", "King of Hittites", "King of Judah" , "King of Tyre");
        this.createWhoItem(q10);
    }
}//END MySQLiteHelper Class
```

Here is the activity class:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<QuestionsTable> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    QuestionsTable currentQ;

    Button btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD;
    Button butSkip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        MySQLiteHelper db=new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllWhos();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        final TextView txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewQuestion);
        new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewTimer);
                textView.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " seconds remaining");
                setQuestionView();
            }
            public void setQuestionView(){
                txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQuestion());
                btnA.setText(currentQ.getMultipleChoiceA());
                btnB.setText(currentQ.getMultipleChoiceB());
                btnC.setText(currentQ.getMultipleChoiceC());
                btnD.setText(currentQ.getMultipleChoiceD());
                qid++;
            }

            public void onClickQuestion(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case btnOptionA:
                        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(btnA.getText())) {
                            score++;
                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                        }
                        break;
                    case btnOptionB:
                        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(btnB.getText())) {
                            score++;
                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                        }
                        break;
                    case btnOptionC:
                        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(btnC.getText())) {
                            score++;
                            Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnOptionD:
                        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equals(btnD.getText())) {
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewTimer);
                textView.setText("Done!");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }.start();

    }
}
```

Here is the logcat from Android Studio

```
04-08 17:55:07.982 3741-3748/com.example.dan.biblechallenge I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
04-08 17:55:14.665 3741-3741/com.example.dan.biblechallenge I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-08 17:55:26.299 3741-3741/com.example.dan.biblechallenge E/MySQLiteHelper: SELECT  * FROM who
04-08 17:55:26.302 3741-3741/com.example.dan.biblechallenge E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error
04-08 17:55:26.302 3741-3741/com.example.dan.biblechallenge D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-08 17:55:26.303 3741-3741/com.example.dan.biblechallenge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.dan.biblechallenge, PID: 3741
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dan.biblechallenge/com.example.dan.biblechallenge.QuestionActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE who(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, who_question TEXT,who_multiple_choiceAText,who_multiple_choiceBText,who_multiple_choiceCText,who_multiple_choiceDText,who_answerText,)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE who(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, who_question TEXT,who_multiple_choiceAText,who_multiple_choiceBText,who_multiple_choiceCText,who_multiple_choiceDText,who_answerText,)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                                                  at com.example.dan.biblechallenge.MySQLiteHelper.onCreate(MySQLiteHelper.java:173)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                                  at com.example.dan.biblechallenge.MySQLiteHelper.getAllWhos(MySQLiteHelper.java:216)
                                                                                  at com.example.dan.biblechallenge.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:42)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: `SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error`... Did you read this?

Comment: If you can read that, please, look at `who_multiple_choiceAText` and notice that you are missing spaces around `Text,`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry about everything, I have been on this stage of the project for a number of days. It looks like even after cleaning the error up it still crashes. Any help?

Comment: Now I get this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: That's a separate error which means you need to [edit] your question with the newest logcat. But again, we aren't here to help you interpret the logcat. You should be able to see exactly which line causes the error if you learn to read it. You have some list (or Cursor) that is empty, and you have tried to access the first element (or column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your Table create Query with below.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_WHO = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_WHO  + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_WHO_QUESTION
        + " TEXT," + KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEA + "Text," + KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEB + "Text," +
         KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICEC + "Text," +KEY_WHO_MULTIPLE_CHOICED + "Text," + KEY_WHO_ANSWER + "Text" + ")";
```